# When using the Paramiko rename function to change the name of a file in a new directory I get an error

Tags: python, paramiko

Currently, I am using Paramiko to connect to an `Sftp` server to find a file and then rename the file in a new directory. I can use `sftp.get()` to get the file and place it in my directory, however, when I use rename, I receive an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file.
```

The file does exist cause I can go to the `sftp` server and find the file and also because I can use `sftp.get()`. The final call looks like the following:

edit: (added the file paths)

```
StudentLitemaxfilepath = '/SchoolDistricts/South Orangetown/Level 0 Auto Imports/NY500301_StudentLite_SFTP_202402271345.csv

new_student_lite_path = X:/L0AutoImport/NY500301_STUDENT_LITE_UPDATE_2024_02_27.csv

sftp.rename(StudentLitemaxfilepath, new_student_lite_path)
```

The path includes the old name of the file and the path on `StudenLitemaxfilepath` and it includes the new name and new path on new_student_lite_path. The weird thing is I got it to work a couple of days before, but now it's not working. Let me know if I am making a dum mistake. Also, I apologize for anything I did wrong in my post. This is my first question.

I tried using:

`sftp.rename(StudentLitemaxfilepath, new_student_lite_path)`

and was expecting the file from the first path to be moved to the second path with a new name. Instead I got the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file.
```

Note: For some reason the sftp.get() works but I do not understand why. I was able to get and move the file to a new directory and even change its name. Exactly how sftp.rename() should work.

Comment: a [repro] please.

Comment: Show us the actual path or at the very least their syntax. + Post log of any SFTP client that can succeed with this rename using the same credentials.